# Emacs: fill all text except indicated regions

Tags: text, emacs, elisp, fill

Using elisp within gnu emacs, I'd like to be able to fill all text in the buffer except for text that is indicated with special identifiers. The identifers can be just about anything, but for the sake of this question, let's just assume that it's any text that falls between [nofill] and [/nofill] tags.

For example, assume that my buffer looks like this:

```
Now is the time
for all good
   men to come to the aid
    of their party. Now is
the time for all good
 men to come to the aid
of their party.

[nofill]
The quick
brown fox
jumped over the
lazy sleeping dog
[/nofill]

When in the course of 
    human events, it becomes 
  it becomes necessary for one
     people to dissolve the
  political bands

[nofill]
    baa-baa
      black sheep,
   have you
    any wool
[/nofill]
```

After the kind of filling I'm looking for, I want the buffer to appear as follows:

```
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their
party. Now is the time for all good me to come to the aid of
their party

[nofill]
The quick
brown fox
jumped over the
lazy sleeping dog
[/nofill]

When in the course of human events, it becomes it becomes
necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands

[nofill]
    baa-baa
      black sheep,
   have you
    any wool
[/nofill]
```

I know elisp and I could write something which does this. However, before I attempt to "reinvent the wheel", I'm wondering if anyone knows of any existing elisp modules which might already provide this functionality.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just justify everything between `[/nofill]` and `[nofill]` (or possibly beginning/end of buffer).

```
(defun fill-special () "fill special"
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (< (point) (point-max))
    (let ((start (point)))
      (if (search-forward "[nofill]" nil 1)
          (forward-line -1))
      (fill-region start (point) 'left)
      (if (search-forward "[/nofill]" nil 1)
          (forward-line 1)))))
```

Comment: Well, that was a lot easier than I thought. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This seems overly-complicated compared to the other answer, but basically, I mark the current point, searched forward for a tag (which could be parameterized), and fill the region. Then, I recursively call `fill-region-ignore-tags-helper`, using the first character after the starting point as the start of the region, and then the next `[nofill]` tag as the end of the region. This continues until the entire buffer is filled. It seems to work with some random trivial cases, although there may be some edge cases that aren't covered.

```
(defun fill-region-ignore-tags ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (fill-region-ignore-tags-helper (point-min) (search-forward "[nofill]"))))

(defun fill-region-ignore-tags-helper (begin end)
  (let ((cur-point begin)
        (next-point end))
    (if (eq next-point nil)
        nil
      (progn
        (fill-region cur-point next-point)
        (fill-region-ignore-tags-helper (progn
                                          (search-forward "[/nofill]")
                                          (re-search-forward "\\S-")
                                          (point))
                                 (progn
                                   (search-forward "[nofill]")
                                   (previous-line)
                                   (point)))))))
```

Comment: Yes, works for me, also. Could use "(when next-point ..." as a shorter form than "(if (eq next-point nil) nil (progn ..."